# Обращение к блоку в родителе блока

Tags: html, jquery

Структура банальна:

```
<div class="data_form">
    <div class="newprog">
    Тот который получит текст инпута
    </div>
    <div>
    <input>Тот который я изменяю
    </div>
</div>
```

Как я только не пробовал обратится к нужному блоку, например:

```
$(".data_form:has(".$(this).").newprog").text($(this).val());
```

Остальные варианты стыдно показывать...
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```js
$("div.data_form input").on("keyup", function(e){
    $(e.target).closest(".data_form").find(".newprog").text($(this).val());
});
```

Словами можно описать так: при событии на элементе `input` ищем первый родительский элемент с классом `data_form` и от него вниз ищем элемент с классом `newprog`. Об `event.target` подробней [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Пример [кода](https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/6tfofa46/).

---

Если Вы добавляете блоки с помощью скрипта, то такой пример работать не будет. В таком случае нужно "обернуть" блоки, например в `div` и уже на него "повесить" обработчик события:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".data_form:first").clone().appendTo(".container");
});

$("div.container").on("keyup", "input", function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest(".data_form").find(".newprog").text($(this).val());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add new container</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="data_form">
    <div class="newprog">Текст инпута 1</div>
    <div>
      <input />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/6tfofa46/1/)

Comment: @Levelleor Всё зависит от Вашей разметки. Если она не будет меняться, то вполне рабочий вариант. В противном случае приведенный пример предпочтительней, т.к. не привязан к вложенности `input`. Поправил ответ.

Comment: Окей, большое спасибо за помощь и совет! Я прочитал про delegate() и все получилось.

Answer (score 0):

А `.find()` пробовали?

```js
var 
    input = $('.data_form').find('input'),
    box = $('.data_form').find('.newprog');

input.on('keypress', function(){
  console.log(input.val());
  
  box.text(input.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data_form">
    <div class="newprog">
    Тот который получит текст инпута
    </div>
    <div>
    <input>Тот который я изменяю
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может что-то типа: `$(".data_form.newprog").find(this).text($(this).val());` ? Суть в том что на странице таких блоков может быть безгранично много и потому задача отыскать изменяемый тайтл именно этого блока в котором происходит изменение input'a. Потому задача найти именно через `this`... Кстати этот мой вариант вообще ничего не делает и не выдает ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".prog_name").on('input', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent('.data_form').children('.newprog').text($(this).val());
});
```

Нашел себе такой ответ. Возвращаемся на 2 родителя вверх и выбираем дочерний элемент с указанным классом. Не работает для блоков созданных скриптом почему-то...